# AlertDialog is giving an "undefined" error

Tags: java, android, android-dialog

My code is:

```
View.OnClickListener menuHandle = new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //inflate menu

        final String [] items = new String[] {"Rate This App", "Quit"};
        final Integer[] icons = new Integer[] {R.drawable.star, R.drawable.quit};
        ListAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapterWithIcon(MainActivity.this, items, icons);

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this, R.style.DialogSlideAnim)
            .setAdapter(adapter, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item ) {
                //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Item Selected: " + item, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    switch (item) {
                    case 0:
                        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), items[item], Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                        //Try Google play
                        intent.setData(Uri.parse("market://details?id=com.test.testing"));
                        if (MyStartActivity(intent) == false) {
                            //Market (Google play) app seems not installed, let's try to open a web browser
                            intent.setData(Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?com.test.testing"));
                            if (MyStartActivity(intent) == false) {
                                //Well if this also fails, we have run out of options, inform the user.
                                //let the user know nothing was successful
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        finish();
                        break;
                    default:
                        //do nothing
                    }
                }
            });
        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        alert.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawableResource(android.R.color.transparent);
        alert.getWindow().setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM);
        alert.show();
    }
};
```

I get the following error:

```
The constructor AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity, int) is undefined
```

What do I have to modify to get rid of the error?

Note: My `MainActivity` class extends `Activity` and `DialogSlideAnim` as been initialized in the `res/values/styles.xml` file

Comment: That is there with Dialog only and not with alert dialog

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this, R.style.DialogSlideAnim)` **will work only on API level 11 and above.**

If you are targeting all the platforms then use following.

`AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(new ContextThemeWrapper(MainActivity.this, R.style.DialogSlideAnim))`

Answer (score 1):

try

```
 new AlertDialog.Builder(v.getContext(), R.style.DialogSlideAnim)
```

instead of

```
 new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this, R.style.DialogSlideAnim)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think its because the `AlertDialog.Builder` is inside a `inner class(menuHandle.setOnClickListener)`, try changing to: `new AlertDialog.Builder(TheNameOfYourClass.this,R.style.DialogSlideAnim);`

Like this way :

```
public void onClick(View v) {
new AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this, R.style.DialogSlideAnim);
^^^
 ....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to set the Style in your `AlertDialog` as below:

> ```
>   new AlertDialog.Builder(
>      new ContextThemeWrapper(MainActivity.this, R.style.DialogSlideAnim)
> ```